# Calculator made with html/javascript doesn't work properly in some devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, windows, browser

I made an app that runs in a web page. This app is a simple calculator that calculate the price of freight/shipping packages to Venezuela. You can choose from 1 to 4 packages, types of freight such as air (normal, express) and maritime(Normal, express). It shows the prices per package and the total.

http://micarritodecompras.com/calculadora/

The issue is that it works perfectly in my laptop(Windows 8.1, HP, chrome, ie, firefox) and in my phone (Nexus 5) but it does with many, many issues in all the laptops in the company owner of the website. Some of the issues is that when clicking on "=" doesn't show the prices; when choosing 2 packages, it shows columns 1,2 and 4!!! when it should only 1 and 2. It doesn't show the radio buttons for Normal/Expreso services. And many others.
They also tried in an iPad with same results.

I have no clue about what is happening here. Maybe some of you can help me.

Thanks in advance

PS: if you need code ask for it, but I think it's not that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it already. There was some cookies in the laptops they were using that didn't let the app function correctly. So, never mind!